# What are the valid values for Application Insights ping test frequency?

Tags: azure-application-insights

The frequency for ping test is just an integer. Looking at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.insights/2015-05-01/webtests, there is no info on what the min and max value could be.

What is the min and max value one can specify for frequency?

Answer (score 0):

The recommended values are 300 (5 min), 600 (10 min) and 900 (15 min).

The min value is 300 (5 min).